# Bootstrap Grid Boxes Overflowing Into Each Other When Window Resized

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap's grid to set up my page to be mobile friendly. I recently ran into the problem of significant overflow from one box into another, but was able to see the fix go away when i applied "display: inline;" to #mainbody. The only issue now is that my columns are displayed vertically instead of horizontally when full windowed. HTML, CSS, and Screenshot below. Appreciate any help.

https://ibb.co/kjRggQ after applying inline

https://ibb.co/esxXo5 stacked vertically

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load embed_video_tags %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content='text/html; charset=utf=8'/>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik+Mono+One" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'/>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }} /static/personal/jquery/jquery.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }} /static/personal/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }} /static/personal/jquery/rango.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'personal/css/fonts.css' %}" type = "text/css"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'personal/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type = "text/css"/>

</head>



<!-- main body -->
<div class='wrapper'>

<body background = "{% static 'personal/img/background3.jpg' %}">

<div class='container-fluid'>
<div >
    <div class="row" id="header"  style = 'background-image: "{% static 'personal/img/divbackground.jpg' %}";'>
        <div class="col-sm"></div>

    </div>


    <div class="row" id="title">
        <div class="col"><img src='{% static 'personal/img/aboutme.png' %}' style="height: 100%; width: 100%; max-width: 530px; max-height: 1000px;"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="row"  id="mainbody">
        <div class="col-sm"><p>Maecenas quis est at purus maximus auctor. Maecenas varius tortor quis diam varius, eu ornare mauris mattis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla iaculis, ipsum quis tincidunt rutrum, nisi sem posuere nunc, in rhoncus massa ipsum consectetur risus. Curabitur at dolor non enim varius condimentum. Vestibulum lobortis sed tortor ac mattis.
        </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm"><p id="bodytext">Maecenas quis est at purus maximus auctor. Maecenas varius tortor quis diam varius, eu ornare mauris mattis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla iaculis, ipsum quis tincidunt rutrum, nisi sem posuere nunc, in rhoncus massa ipsum consectetur risus. Curabitur at dolor non enim varius condimentum. Vestibulum lobortis sed tortor ac mattis.
        </p></div>
        <div class="col-sm"><p>Maecenas quis est at purus maximus auctor. Maecenas varius tortor quis diam varius, eu ornare mauris mattis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla iaculis, ipsum quis tincidunt rutrum, nisi sem posuere nunc, in rhoncus massa ipsum consectetur risus. Curabitur at dolor non enim varius condimentum. Vestibulum lobortis sed tortor ac mattis.
        </p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="title">
        <div class="col"><img src='{% static 'personal/img/influencers.png' %}' style="height: 100%; width: 100%; max-width: 530px; max-height: 1000px;"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="row"  id="mainbody">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"  id="imagelist">

            <center>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'personal/css/influencersimages.css' %}" type = "text/css"/>

            <a href = '/joerogan/'><img src="{% static 'personal/img/JoeRogansmall.jpg' %}" class="img"  id="Joe Rogan">


            <a href = '/seneca/'><img src="{% static 'personal/img/Senecasmall.jpg' %}" class="img"  id="Seneca">


            <a href = '/peterthiel/'><img src="{% static 'personal/img/peterthielsmall.jpg' %}" class="img"  id="Peter Thiel">

            <a href = '/timferris/'><img src="{% static 'personal/img/TimFerrissmall.jpg' %}" class="img"  id="Tim Ferris">

            <a href = '/markcuban/'><img src="{% static 'personal/img/MarkCubansmall.jpg' %}" class="img"  id="Mark Cuban"></a>

            <button  onclick ='showDiv()'> <img  src="{% static 'personal/img/Jockosmall.jpg' %}" class="img"  id="jocko" > </button>

            </center>

    </div>
</div>

<div id="welcomeDiv"  style="display:none; margin: 0; border: 2px white solid;" class="answer_list">

    <div class="row"  id="mainbody">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><img  src="{% static 'personal/img/Jocko.jpg' %}" class='influencersimage'>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><p>Maecenas quis est at purus maximus auctor. Maecenas varius tortor quis diam varius, eu ornare mauris mattis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla iaculis, ipsum quis tincidunt rutrum, nisi sem posuere nunc, in rhoncus massa ipsum consectetur risus. Curabitur at dolor non enim varius condimentum. Vestibulum lobortis sed tortor ac mattis.
        </p></div>

    </div>

</div>


<div class="row" id="title">
    <div class="col"><img src='{% static 'personal/img/bucketlist.png' %}' style="height: 100%; width: 100%; max-width: 530px; max-height: 1000px;"></div>
</div>

<div class="col"  id="mainbody">
    <ol  class="olcenter">
      <b>
    <li class='bucket'>example</li>
    <li class='bucket'>example</li>
    <li class='bucket'>example</li>
    <li class='bucket'>example</li>
    <li class='bucket'>example</li>

    </ol>
   </div>
</div>


<div class="row" id="title">
    <div class="col"><img src='{% static 'personal/img/contactme.png' %}' style="height: 100%; width: 100%; max-width: 530px; max-height: 1000px;"></div>

</div>
<div class="row"  id="mainbody">
    <div class="col-sm-4"><p>Maecenas quis est at purus maximus auctor. Maecenas varius tortor quis diam varius, eu ornare mauris mattis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;
    </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><p id="bodytext">Maecenas quis est at purus maximus auctor. Maecenas varius tortor quis diam varius, eu ornare mauris mattis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;
    </p></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><p>Maecenas quis est at purus maximus auctor. Maecenas varius tortor quis diam varius, eu ornare mauris mattis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;
    </p></div>
</div>



{% block content %}
{% endblock %}




</body>
</div>

</html>



body {

    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;

}

.wrapper {
    width:100%;
}



#mainbody {
    background: white;
    height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    color: white;
    min-height: 100%;
    display: inline;

    background: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background: transparent;


}



#header {

    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;


}

#title {

    background:white;
    height: 125px;
    margin: auto;
    background-image:
    url('');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background: transparent;
height: 80%;

}

#welcomeDiv {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto 0;

}
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/dXWso5 before applying stacked vertically

Comment: Please clean-up the code to a **minimal** example to repro the issue.